# Tone Mapping image manipulation

Tags: performance, image, vb.net, graphics

This code is extremely slow and ideally I would appreciate someone walking me through getting this going on the GPU, but if nobody has time for that which is understandable, any and all optimisations would be most welcome!

```
Private Sub Picture(source As Image, picturebox As PictureBox)
    Dim r As Double
    Dim g As Double
    Dim b As Double

    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(source)
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height)
    Dim bmpData As System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData = bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.[ReadOnly], bmp.PixelFormat)
    Dim ptr As IntPtr = bmpData.Scan0
    Dim bytes As Integer = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height
    Dim rgbValues As Byte() = New Byte(bytes - 1) {}
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes)

    Dim linWhiteMult = 1 / (((LinearWhiteTextBox.Text * ((ShoulderStrengthTextBox.Text * LinearWhiteTextBox.Text) + (LinearAngleTextBox.Text * LinearStrengthTextBox.Text)) + (ToeStrengthTextBox.Text * ToeNumeratorTextBox.Text)) _
    / (LinearWhiteTextBox.Text * ((ShoulderStrengthTextBox.Text * LinearWhiteTextBox.Text) + LinearStrengthTextBox.Text) + ToeStrengthTextBox.Text * ToeDenominatorTextBox.Text) - (ToeNumeratorTextBox.Text / ToeDenominatorTextBox.Text)))

    'precalculations for optimisation

    Dim LaLs = LinearAngleTextBox.Text * LinearStrengthTextBox.Text
    Dim TsTn = ToeStrengthTextBox.Text * ToeNumeratorTextBox.Text
    Dim TsTd = ToeStrengthTextBox.Text * ToeDenominatorTextBox.Text
    Dim Tn_Td = ToeNumeratorTextBox.Text / ToeDenominatorTextBox.Text

    Dim list As New List(Of String)
    For x As Integer = 0 To bmp.Width - 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To bmp.Height - 1
            Dim position As Integer = (y * bmpData.Stride) + (x * Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bmpData.PixelFormat) / 8)
            b = rgbValues(position)
            g = rgbValues(position + 1)
            r = rgbValues(position + 2)

            '^2.2 lookup table (for optimisation) for gamma correction 

            b = table.Item(b)
            g = table.Item(g)
            r = table.Item(r)

'the following is the filmic tone map formula, i.e.
'x*(A*x+C*B)+D*E)/(x*(A*x+B)+D*F)) - E/F

            r = (((r * ((ShoulderStrengthTextBox.Text * r) + (LaLs)) + (TsTn)) _
                    / (r * ((ShoulderStrengthTextBox.Text * r) + LinearStrengthTextBox.Text) + TsTd) - (Tn_Td))) * linWhiteMult

            g = (((g * ((ShoulderStrengthTextBox.Text * g) + (LaLs)) + (TsTn)) _
                    / (g * ((ShoulderStrengthTextBox.Text * g) + LinearStrengthTextBox.Text) + TsTd) - (Tn_Td))) * linWhiteMult

            b = (((b * ((ShoulderStrengthTextBox.Text * b) + (LaLs)) + (TsTn)) _
                    / (b * ((ShoulderStrengthTextBox.Text * b) + LinearStrengthTextBox.Text) + TsTd) - (Tn_Td))) * linWhiteMult
            If r > 1 Then
                r = 1
            End If
            If g > 1 Then
                g = 1
            End If
            If b > 1 Then
                b = 1
            End If

            rgbValues(position) = Math.Round((b ^ 0.45) * 255)
            rgbValues(position + 1) = Math.Round((g ^ 0.45) * 255)
            rgbValues(position + 2) = Math.Round((r ^ 0.45) * 255)

        Next
    Next

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes)

    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData)

    ' apply the bmp to the avatars and dispose old

    Dim OldImage = picturebox.Image
    picturebox.Image = bmp
    OldImage.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Comment: Friend of mine pointed out that taking the string parsing out of the loop is an obvious way to speed it up - he was right, it's now lightning fast :)

Answer (score 1):

First, I have to say that you are using good variable names.

**Turn Option Strict On**

This setting is important, it'll help you see errors and needed conversion.

You'll notice that this isn't possible

> ```
> Dim LaLs = LinearAngleTextBox.Text * LinearStrengthTextBox.Text
> ```

But instead you need to convert it to integer.

```
Dim LaLs = Int32.Parse(LinearAngleTextBox.Text) * Int32.Parse(LinearStrengthTextBox.Text)
```

**Don't repeat yourself**

You'll then notice that some conversions are done often.

> ```
> Int32.Parse(LinearStrengthTextBox.Text)
> ```

Put these in proper variable right at the begining.

```
Dim linearStrength As Integer = Int32.Parse(LinearStrengthTextBox.Text)
```

There are formula like the below that are done in the inner loop, which can be moved outside of the loop.

```
(x * Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bmpData.PixelFormat) / 8)
```